# Terminator on KDE: Impossible to select text in terminal to copy it

Tags: linux, terminal, kde, kubuntu, terminator

### Issue

I have an issue a bit odd, I am using [terminator](https://terminator-gtk3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for the terminal and somehow it's impossible to select text from the terminal with the mouse, meaning I can't copy anything from the terminal, and that's really annoying.

The text get selected as long as I hold the left button on the mouse, but when I release it, it directly get unselected, and nothing is copied.  If I press Shift, the selections hold until I release shift but doesn't get copied even if I press `Ctrl+Shift+C`.

It doesn't seem linked to the hardware/OS as the KDE default terminal `Konsole` is not having this issue.

Did anyone experienced this already ?
Any idea how to fix it ?

### System info

- OS: Kubuntu 21.04
- UI: KDE Plasma 5.21.4
- Terminator version 2.1.0

*Please comment the Question if something is not clear*

Comment: If you select the text and then press the middle button, does it get pasted in the terminal? (on Linux, you can select text in a terminal and then directly paste it wherever you want with the middle button).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, may be you have to update to latest version, there is a  fix in 2.1.2 release

[https://github.com/gnome-terminator/terminator/releases/tag/v2.1.2#:~:text=Bug%20Fix%3A%20%27Clear%20selection%20on%20copy%27%20is%20always%20unchecked%20by%20%40Vulcalien%20in%20%23443](https://github.com/gnome-terminator/terminator/releases/tag/v2.1.2#:%7E:text=Bug%20Fix%3A%20%27Clear%20selection%20on%20copy%27%20is%20always%20unchecked%20by%20%40Vulcalien%20in%20%23443)